# How to choose the best type of controls to use in a toolbar?

Tags: gui-design, toolbar

I have a 3D view displaying two objects. One is the reference object, the other the user object. Displaying the two objects together allows the user to compare its own object to a reference object (these objects are gamuts).

Each object have three display modes (smooth, wireframe and flat) and an opacity selector (a slider ranging from 0 to 100).

There also are controls that are "gamuts independent" : a selector to chose from 2D to 3D, a "Top View" and a "Bottom View" buttons and a slider, called Gamut Slice on the following picture.

The picture represents what we have today, but we wish to redesign this window.

[image]

(The two check boxes "New Profile" and "Reference Profile" are not useful and will be deleted.)

I'd like to integrate all the control elements in a toolbar, but I don't know which criterion are the best to determine the controls I should be using.

Especially, I would like to somehow regroup the display modes Smooth, Wireframe, and Flat together. I thought of two possible solutions : using three separate buttons (one for each mode), or using a combo box with the three modes. There are probably plenty of other possible solutions.

On what criterion should I make my choices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try don't redo the wheel. Use global patterns of icons, names and functions**.

See some tasks to define the best controls to use:

- Have a look at what your **competitors and similar tools** are doing. Don't do too different because could increase the learning time.
- Define **what type of control** do you need and analyse each one individually. List them and writes how each function show behave. Also, look at the user expectation.
- Have a look at **the precision of input** and how easy is to manipulate on the chosen platform/operational system.

After all that, redesign your wireframe, design it and **prototype** it. If still having doubts, bring to us and **test with your users** (not developers and owners, real users).

I suggest you read this article: [The ultimate guide for selection controls in UX design](https://blog.prototypr.io/how-to-choose-and-design-selection-controls-in-ux-ba4a68344118)

Look some interesting control settings, as a reference, that I found on fast research.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Good point about prototyping, I must say that we don't often prototype before coding...